# How to get values of arrays from group in created element

Tags: javascript

I have made a function in javascript to get values of arrays grouped in single variable on clickevent. I want when i click a button once the values of 1st set of array in the group is passed to element which i have created through javascript and then the 2nd set of array on click of button 2nd time and so on. In my function the values of the sets is replacing in first created element and showing undefined value in other created elements. Kindly help me out.

```js
a = 0;

function myFunction5() {
  var carsglb = [
    ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
    ["Baleno", "Elitei20", "Glanza"],
    ["Petrol", "Diesel", "CNG"]
  ]; // In this way we can combine multiple set of   arrays into single array.

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var p1 = document.createElement("p");
  var p2 = document.createElement("p");
  var p3 = document.createElement("p");


  div.append(p1, p2, p3);
  if (a < carsglb.length) {
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("div > p");

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML = carsglb[a][i];

  }
  a++;

}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Onclick extract arrays set one by one</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction5()">Get Multiples Ist Method</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're searching the document for all `div>p` elements, which includes the ones you've already finished with. You could use a different selector to only change the newest 3, but a much better solution is to add the car names to the `p` elements before actually writing them to the DOM, like done below. This also has the benefit of doing the `p` creation and appending in a loop, so you don't have to have 3 lots of them.

```js
a = 0;
function myFunction5() {
    var carsglb = [["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"], ["Baleno", "Elitei20", "Glanza"], ["Petrol", "Diesel", "CNG"]]; // In this way we can combine multiple set of arrays into single array.
    if ( a < carsglb.length) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");

        var i;
        for (i=0; i < carsglb[a].length; i++) {
          var p = document.createElement("p");
          p.innerHTML = carsglb[a][i];
          div.append(p);
        }
        a++;  

        document.body.appendChild(div);  
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div > p");
```

with

```
var x = div.querySelectorAll("p");
```

otherwise you will always replace all of your paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `p` from `div` object not from `document`.

`var x = div.querySelectorAll("p");` will return all `p` element inside `div` object. You were getting incorrect result because you have used `document.querySelectorAll("div > p");` which will return all the `p` elements with parent as `div` element in entire `body`.

Also you should `return;` for `if (a >= carsglb.length)`.

```js
a = 0;

function myFunction5() {
  var carsglb = [
    ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
    ["Baleno", "Elitei20", "Glanza"],
    ["Petrol", "Diesel", "CNG"]
  ]; // In this way we can combine multiple set of   arrays into single array.

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var p1 = document.createElement("p");
  var p2 = document.createElement("p");
  var p3 = document.createElement("p");


  div.append(p1, p2, p3);
  if (a >= carsglb.length) {
    return;      
  }

  document.body.appendChild(div);
  var x = div.querySelectorAll("p");

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML = carsglb[a][i];
  }

  a++;

}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Onclick extract arrays set one by one</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction5()">Get Multiples Ist Method</button>
```